# jquery .load php with get-variable

Tags: php, jquery, get

I have a while-loop which includes ID.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo '<li class="li"><a href="#?id=' . $row['id'] . '" onClick="showTicket(' . $row['id'] . ')">' . $row['rubrik'] . '</a></li>';
}
```

where I included the fetched ID in `showTicket()` . How do I get the variable in my jquery? See below code:

```
function showTicket() {
$(".open").load("ticket.php");
$('.open').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
}
```

I want the .load to be like this: ticket.php?id=(id-variable)

Comment: `function showTicket(ticketid) {
$(".open").load("ticket.php?id=" + ticketid);
}`

Comment: Thanks mate, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showTicket(id){
alert('ID--'+id)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="li" onClick="showTicket(25)"><a href="#?id=25" ></a>Click here to Send Id</li>
```

Comment: Where's the PHP in this answer?

Comment: I have given static data, append php value in place of static data

Comment: HOW does OP append php value in place of static data, I think that's what OP is asking